# Difference between two files

Tags: shell-script, diff, file-comparison

I have two files , say a & b. I want to compare both the files and get the differences in the third file along with the file name. Can anyone help me out with a simple command.

Comment: have you try `man diff` ?

Answer (score 2):

`diff a b > differences` should do the job. The differences between the two files will be stored in the file `differences`.

Comment: I have ">" in both of my files so how to take that into account?

Comment: @SaketAgarwal `diff "a>weird>filename" "b>also>weird>filename" > differences`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [grep](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm) function to see the difference (file3 is the output file):

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2 > file3
```

Where the flags are:

- `-F` : Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
- `-x` : Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
- `-v` : Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
- `-f` FILE : Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

Use flag `-n` : Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input file:

```
grep -n -Fxvf file1 file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 1):

## gnu diff

provided you have gnu diff (from diffutils, `diff (GNU diffutils) 3.3`).

```
diff --old-line-format='old %L' --new-line-format='new %L' --unchanged-group-format='' u v

old    PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c0t4d0
new    PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c99t4d0
```

(redirecting to a file is explain below).

## basic diff with awk

with basic diff, use awk to parse '<' and '>'

```
diff u v
178c178
<    PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c0t4d0
---
>    PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c99t4d0
```

use awk to put file name

```
 diff u v | awk '$1 == "<" { printf "u: %s\n",$0; next ; } 
            $1 == ">" { printf "v: %s\n",$0 ; next ; } 
            { print;} '

178c178
u: <    PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c0t4d0
---
v: >    PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c99t4d0
```

(awk lines splitted for readability)

now to store into a diff file

```
diff u v | awk '$1 == "<" { printf "u: %s\n",$0; next ; } $1 == ">" { printf "v: %s\n",$0 ; next ; } { print;} ' > differences
```